# What does <training samples> and <validation samples> mean?

Tags: python, machine-learning, syntax-error, conv-neural-network

I got this code from Github, it is an open source glaucoma detection machine learning algorithm that uses a convolutional network to classify retinal images into yes/no glaucoma:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Activation, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
from keras import backend as K
from keras import optimizers
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, ReduceLROnPlateau
from imgaug import augmenters as iaa

img_width, img_height = 256, 256
input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

train_data_dir = "data/train"
validation_data_dir = "data/validation"
nb_train_samples = <training samples>
nb_validation_samples = <validation samples>
batch_size = 16
epochs = 100

input = Input(shape=input_shape)

block1 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_0')(input)

# Block 1
block1 = Conv2D(8, (3,3), name='conv_11', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), name='conv_12', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), name='conv_13', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_14', activation='relu')(block1)
block1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block1)
block1 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_1')(block1)

block1 = Conv2D(16, 1)(block1)

# Block 2
block2 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), name='conv_21', activation='relu')(block1)
block2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_22', activation='relu')(block2)
block2 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_23', activation='relu')(block2)
block2 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), name='conv_24', activation='relu')(block2)
block2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block2)
block2 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_2')(block2)

block2 = Conv2D(64, 1)(block2)

# Block 3
block3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_31', activation='relu')(block2)
block3 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), name='conv_32', activation='relu')(block3)
block3 = Conv2D(128, (3,3), name='conv_33', activation='relu')(block3)
block3 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_34', activation='relu')(block3)
block3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block3)
block3 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_3')(block3)

# Block 4
block4 = Conv2D(64, (3,3), name='conv_41', activation='relu')(block3)
block4 = Conv2D(32, (3,3), name='conv_42', activation='relu')(block4)
block4 = Conv2D(16, (3,3), name='conv_43', activation='relu')(block4)
block4 = Conv2D(8, (2,2), name='conv_44', activation='relu')(block4)
block4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(block4)
block4 = BatchNormalization(name='norm_4')(block4)

block4 = Conv2D(2, 1)(block4)

block5 = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(block4)
output = Activation('softmax')(block5)

model = Model(inputs=[input], outputs=[output])
model.summary()
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False), metrics=["accuracy"])

# Initiate the train and test generators with data Augumentation
sometimes = lambda aug: iaa.Sometimes(0.6, aug)
seq = iaa.Sequential([
                      iaa.GaussianBlur(sigma=(0 , 1.0)),
                      iaa.Sharpen(alpha=1, lightness=0),
                      iaa.CoarseDropout(p=0.1, size_percent=0.15),
                              sometimes(iaa.Affine(
                                                    scale={"x": (0.8, 1.2), "y": (0.8, 1.2)},
                                                    translate_percent={"x": (-0.2, 0.2), "y": (-0.2, 0.2)},
                                                    rotate=(-30, 30),
                                                    shear=(-16, 16)))
                    ])


train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    preprocessing_function=seq.augment_image,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip=True)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode="categorical")

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_height, img_width),
    class_mode="categorical")

checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint("f1.h5", monitor='acc', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=False, mode='auto', period=1)
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.1, patience=2, verbose=0, mode='auto', cooldown=0, min_lr=0)

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
    callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce_lr]
)
```

except I keep getting this error:

```
File "CNN.py", line 15
    nb_train_samples = <training samples>
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What should I replace `<training samples>` and `<validation samples>` with in order to not get this error? Other than this, the rest of the code works.

Thank you all, Satya

Comment: You're supposed to enter the **number** of training and validation samples there. Furthermore, for this code to execute you'll need to have valid training and validation samples in the `data/training` and `training/validation` subfolders to your working directory on your PC

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fill this in terms of code but I can tell what training and validation samples are.

training samples are data which are used to train a model. a model learns to give some output for particular sample. But we don't really want to teach a model to recognize just samples but we expect to recognize 'patterns'

that's why we use validation data. to ensure that model not only works well with samples used to learn but works also good with samples which 'haven't seen' yet.

It seems that your script expects structure with (256,256,3) for each sample, but code responsible for loading that data is missing yet.

Answer (score 0):

Those numbers refer to the number of Validation and Training samples in the training and validation directories. Also be aware that based on Keras documentation, those directories should contain one subdirectory per class. Any **PNG, JPG, BMP, PPM or TIF** images inside each of the subdirectories directory tree will be included in the generator.

If you don't know how many images you have in those directories or you might add new images into those directories in the future, you can use:

```py
nb_train_samples = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(train_data_dir)])
nb_validation_samples = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(validation_data_dir)])
```

Comment: thank you. That worked, i ran into a new error but i will post a new question for that.